# small font for programming wanted

Tags: fonts, linux, flyspell, x11

I have a low-res screen (1366x768) and therefore are searching for a small font which is clearly readable.
Till now I used this font:

[image: real size and face of font]

-misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--8-80-75-75-c-50-iso10646-1

I had set it up in my .Xdefaults / .Xresources file.
This font has a good size and is very good to read, but it has some drawbacks:
flyspell is not marking the words and It can not show italics. 
(Flyspell is marking words only if I increase fontsize.)

So I am searching for a **monospace font** with **similar size**, which is **good to read**  and **for programming** (i.E. distinguishes letters: 1l, O0, {[<) supports **german letters** (äÄüÜöÖß) and **works with flyspell**. (If it supports italics the better.) It should **work with emacs-lucid on Xorg**.

On my system there are fonts which are smaller and work with flyspell and italics, but they are all hard to read at this size.
I know there is a font out there, I had it once, but I lost it and forgot the name. :(

**Edit**: I changed the face of marking words to just mark with straight underline instead of 'wave', this fixes it.

**Edit**: Even if the Question is closed: I found the font I was searching for, it is called 'neep' it comes with package 'xfonts-jmk' in debian.

Comment: You can change the `flyspell-incorrect` face to change how incorrect words are marked, or change the `line-height` frame parameter so that the wavy underlines fit better.

Comment: db48x: thanks for the sugestion. set the face to mark with straight underline, this works.

Comment: I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug RET` about the fact that the wavy underline didn't work for you.